# How to watermark all files in folder with ffmpeg? (Windows)

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg

I'm using the following command to resize and watermark videos: `ffmpeg -i "input video.mp4" -s 640x480 -vf "movie=watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10 [out]" "output video.mp4"`

With this command I have to add each video line by line. How can I simply do the same thing to all videos in a directory, and specify an output folder? I'm using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a batch shell script. For windows you can use:

```
for %%a in ("C:\path\to\directory\*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -s 640x480 -vf "movie=watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10 [out]" "C:\path\to\output_directory\%%~na.mp4"
pause
```

Just paste the above in your terminal after updating your paths to files, of course.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this working after monkeying around with this for a few tries.

This is what I came up with that works great..

1) I put the following files/folders INSIDE the same folder with ALL of the videos I want to be watermarked.

a) ffmpeg

b) an empty output folder named "newfiles"

c) the intended watermark image named "watermark-image.png"

d) the batch file named "watermark.bat"

2) Place the following code into the bat file:

```
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i watermark-image.png -filter_complex "overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2" -codec:a copy "newfiles\%%~na.mp4" pause
```

3) Works perfectly! This script will do your entire folder of videos at once.

Thanks to the contributors before me that I pieced this together from.

PS:

i. I sized my watermark png to the exact dimensions of my video for simple perfect 
       logo placement.

ii. Operating System: Windows 10

Kindly, Brandon

Answer (score 0):

convert mp4 to mkv and add water mark top right corner

1) I put the following files/folders INSIDE the same folder with ALL of the videos I want to be watermarked.

a) ffmpeg

b) an empty output folder named "newfiles"

c) the intended watermark image named logo.png (best size 96x22)

d) inside the videos folder Shift+right click

e)Open PowerShell window here

f)$cmd

input the $ below

```
for %i in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%i" -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10" -codec:a copy "newfiles\%~ni.mkv"
```

Thanks to the contributors before